# create a function pointer in C with a value from another function

Tags: function, pointers

I am searching for a way to create a function pointer in C(++) with a function using a parameter to add it to the scope of the created function, like this example in python:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

def create_function(y):
  def addY(x):
    return add(x, y)
  return addY

add5 = create_function(5)
print add5(2)
# 7
```

the value `y` can be given as class instance or pointer, as long as i can access it in `addY`.

Comment: Have you tried looking up some examples on Google? This is pretty good: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: of course, but they are just explaining how to get function pointers into variables, not how to get variables into functions, if you want so. It's hard to google for anything relevant, because the keywords are always leading to general function pointer howtos, without any mention if somehow the function can be influenced before referencing to it.

Comment: The point is, the variable from the outer function should become a constant in the inner one and then the inner one is returned. If its passed by value or reference is irrelevant to me, as the variable will be available in the scope of the function using the function pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really solve the problem with C, but C++ offers [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/).
Together with the possiblity to `typedef` the parameter of the function (its CGAL, which does a lot with templates), i could use the bound function as parameter.

This is the blogentry, where i found the solution: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=4034

I first tried std::bind and then got the same errors, which lead to this post when googling the error message.

If you have a suggestion, how it works with plain C functions as well, i would still be interested what's possible.